# Program to create window transparency in XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, transparency

I'm looking for a program to create window transparency within Windows XP; somewhat like Glass2K.  I've used Glass2K and found it extremely processor intensive and would like to try something else.

The application needs to act upon the current Windows Theme rather than be a theme itself like Aero Glass.

Comment: wrong place for such questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for [PowerMenu](http://www.abstractpath.com/powermenu/).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I downloaded and installed powermenu and it looks cool and seems to work the way I want; however, it does not allow the transparency setting to be saved, therefore every time the menu is opened I have to set the transparency value...any way to alleviate this?

Comment: I don't believe so. Reading the comments from the creator's website (from the link) reveals many other people like you that like the software but pine for the save function.  

The author does have a twitter account, so perhaps you could nudge him into updating his creation.  He did mention that there is a new version coming up at the end of the regular blog post.